# como dar estilos al atributo title de la atiqueta img

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass, less

me gustaria que el atributo de title se pueda estilizar por css para que quede como un tooltip. lo intentado de muchas formas pero no logro hacerlo.

```
<div>
  <img src="image.png" alt="Soy una imagen" title="Soy una imagen" />
</div>
```

Comment: No es posible estilizar ese elemento, puesto que es parte de la interfaz del usuario que el navegador implementa aparte del renderizado HTML, CSS.

Comment: Deberás usar un plugin para Javascript como este: https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/

Answer (score 1):

No es posible darle estilos a la interfaz de usuario nativa del navegador, pero si tu propósito es que aparezca ese texto cuando pasas el cursor sobre la imagen, puedes crear un `tooltip` muy rápido con css sólo resta que lo personalices con tus propios estilos

```css
.tooltip .tooltip-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 20px
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-content {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltip-content">Tooltip text</span>
  <span>Cualquier elemento</span>
</div>
```